# Qt5: error: ‘qt_metacall’ is not a member of

Tags: c++, qt

I try to become more familiar with singnals and slots with Qt.
I want to emit a signal in one class and want to handle it at one other.
Here my example code:

*main.c*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class Emiter
{

signals:
    void anSignal ();
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void handleEmitter ();

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto emiter = new Emiter();

    connect( emiter,
             &Emiter::anSignal,
             this,
             &MainWindow::handleEmitter );
}

void
MainWindow::handleEmitter()
{
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
error: ‘qt_metacall’ is not a member of ‘Emiter’          enum { Value =  sizeof(test(&Object::qt_metacall)) == sizeof(int) };
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Signals and slots are available only in `QObject` derived classes, and a `Q_OBJECT` macro is needed.

```
class Emiter : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:

signals:
   void anSignal ();
};
```

For more detail answer: [click here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Q_OBJECT_Macro_Meta_Object.php)

Answer (score 5):

Another case is if you use multiple inheritances, you need to put `QObject` as the first parent class.